# How to blank other rows having same column detail

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, dense-rank

Hi below is my sql query as

```
SELECT 
o.OrderNumber, 
oi.Sku, 
Sum(Isnull(oi.Price * oi.Quantity,0)) as Price, 
DENSE_RANK() over(partition by o.orderNumber order by oi.sku) as CouponRowId
from ac_OrderItems oi 
inner join ac_Orders o on oi.OrderId = o.OrderId
Inner Join ac_OrderShipments os on oi.OrderShipmentId =os.OrderShipmentId
WHERE (oi.OrderItemTypeId IN (5))
group by o.OrderNumber, oi.Sku
```

and below is the record I am getting

```
OrderNumber    Sku           Price     CouponRowId
90061          BLACKBERRY   -5.6900    1
90061          LEMON        -5.6900    2
90061          PEACH        -5.6900    3
90061          SHIP100      -10.920    4
```

but I want my record as

```
OrderNumber    Sku           Price     
90061          BLACKBERRY   -5.6900    
               LEMON        -5.6900    
               PEACH        -5.6900   
               SHIP100      -10.920
```

I want that if order number is same in that case all detail record should come in 1st row and then after other record should only show Sku and price only and also we need to remove the DENSE_RANK() column

Comment: That is something you should solve in UI. If say you are using C# or any other .Net language, you could use Linq and group by. That would show as you want.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I need this in query only

Comment: Then you could add ROW_NUMBER and using that value blank rows that have a ROW_NUMBER value greater than 1. I can't see its usefulness. Where exactly you would use that result? If OrderNumber is unique, CouponRowID could be used.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I have one console application which used to generate excel using such data fetching from sql, Currently I have just .exe file of that application, So I need to fix this things on query end

Comment: BTW you could use Excel "pivot" thus you don't need to solve it on query (would even do the sum() for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By seeing the query seems like `Partition` Clause can help you to
>   resolve the issue. Please look at the below query. I am not so sure
>   about the data model, but looks like you need to partition by using
>   the `OrderNumber` column. Please replace the query in the first `CTE` with your actual table which will be like the second query. I cant test it since I don't have the environment. Please test the query

```
;WITH CTE_Table
AS
(
SELECT 90061 'OrderNumber' , 'BLACKBERRY' Sku,   -5.6900 'Price',   1 'CouponRowId' UNION
SELECT 90061, 'LEMON', -5.6900, 2  UNION
SELECT 90061, 'PEACH', -5.6900, 3  UNION
SELECT 90061, 'SHIP100', -10.920, 4 UNION
SELECT 90062 'OrderNumber' , 'BLACKBERRY' Sku,   -5.6900 'Price',   1 'CouponRowId' UNION
SELECT 90062, 'LEMON', -5.6900, 2  UNION
SELECT 90062, 'PEACH', -5.6900, 3  UNION
SELECT 90062, 'SHIP100', -10.920, 4 
),
CTE_New
AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNumber ORDER BY OrderNumber) Patrn FROM CTE_Table
)
SELECT CASE WHEN Patrn =1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),OrderNumber) ELSE '' END OrderNumber, Sku, Price, CouponRowId FROM CTE_New



;WITH CTE_Table
AS
(
SELECT 
o.OrderNumber, 
oi.Sku, 
Sum(Isnull(oi.Price * oi.Quantity,0)) as Price, 
DENSE_RANK() over(partition by o.orderNumber order by oi.sku) as CouponRowId
from ac_OrderItems oi 
inner join ac_Orders o on oi.OrderId = o.OrderId
Inner Join ac_OrderShipments os on oi.OrderShipmentId =os.OrderShipmentId
WHERE (oi.OrderItemTypeId IN (5))
group by o.OrderNumber, oi.Sku 
),
CTE_New
AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNumber ORDER BY OrderNumber) Patrn FROM CTE_Table
)
SELECT CASE WHEN Patrn =1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),OrderNumber) ELSE '' END OrderNumber, Sku, Price, CouponRowId FROM CTE_New
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your comment this is an attempt to solve it on the query itself (I assumed CouponRowID might do the job, if OrderNumber is unique):

```
WITH
    tmp AS (
               SELECT o.OrderNumber, oi.Sku, SUM(ISNULL(oi.Price * oi.Quantity, 0)) AS Price, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY o.orderNumber ORDER BY oi.sku) AS CouponRowId
               FROM ac_OrderItems oi
                    INNER JOIN ac_Orders o ON oi.OrderId=o.OrderId
                    INNER JOIN ac_OrderShipments os ON oi.OrderShipmentId=os.OrderShipmentId
               WHERE(oi.OrderItemTypeId IN (5))
               GROUP BY o.OrderNumber, oi.Sku
           )
SELECT CASE WHEN tmp.CouponRowId=1 THEN tmp.OrderNumber END AS OrderNumber, tmp.Sku, tmp.Price
FROM tmp
ORDER BY tmp.OrderNumber, tmp.SKu;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry....! I cant understand your explanations..
I just worked only for get your expected OP...

```
create table #ac_OrderItems(id varchar(20) --varchar, i used instead of int.Beside, varchar is easy to change to int. 
, Sku varchar(20), Price decimal, CouponRowId int)

insert into #ac_OrderItems values(
90061 , 'BLACKBERRY' ,   -5.6900 , 1)
,(90061, 'LEMON', -5.6900, 2  )
,(90061, 'PEACH', -5.6900, 3  )
,(90061, 'SHIP100', -10.920, 4 )
,(90062 , 'BLACKBERRY' ,-5.6900 ,   1  )
,(90062, 'LEMON', -5.6900, 2  )
,(90062, 'PEACH', -5.6900, 3  )
,(90062, 'SHIP100', -10.920, 4)

select * from #ac_OrderItems

;with
orders(id, sku, price, couponId, rn)
as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id) from #ac_OrderItems
)select iif(rn = 1,id,''),sku,price,couponId from orders
-- if i used int, empty is denoted by 0. But you want '' this. So i used varchar id
```

let you know me, what you got.